# Returning the future hours of operation

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to search for venues through an `"Open Till at least"` filter.

The issue I'm having is, that some venues operate through hours of `8AM` to `6PM`, and some from `10PM` to `3AM`. A Nice SO member helped me create this code, but when I tried to modify it for search, I noticed an issue.

If I query for a venue that's open `till at least 20:00`, and the venue opening times are from `11AM` to `21:00`, then everything is *ok*.

But if I query for a venue with opening hours `till at least 20:00` and the operating hours are from `21:00` to `03:00`, then `closed` is returned.

How can I show the hours of operation for venues which are still closed?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
e.VENUE_NAME,
hrs.opening_day,
hrs.opening_time,
hrs.closing_time
FROM hours_of_operation hrs join venues e
  on hrs.venue_id = e.id
     and not is_closed
     and ((hrs.opening_day=date_format('$phpWhenDate' - INTERVAL (closing_time<opening_time and time('$phpWhenDate')<closing_time) DAY, '%a'))
          AND (closing_time<opening_time XOR
         (time('$phpWhenDate') >= least(opening_time,closing_time)
          and time('$phpWhenDate') < greatest(opening_time, closing_time))))
```

`dataWhenDate` looks like this: 2013-02-21 04:00:00

Basically, I use a slider to select how long I want the venue to be open till at least, and that generates a date to be sent.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I really hope you're [properly escaping your SQL values](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you could end up having a Very Bad Day some time soon.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking a venue which is open between `21:00` and `03:00`, should really return as closed when querying opening hours `till at least 20:00`, because it is opening only at 21:00. If I would be the user it would actually mislead me if `opening hours till at least 20:00` would show a venue which is only opening at `21:00`.

If simply you want to show that which venues are open after `20:00` then just compare `20:00` with the opening and closing hours of the venue and if either is larger than `20:00` then that is open after `20:00` (but you might want to put in an asterisk explaining to the user that being open past `20:00` include venues which are opening after `20:00`).